# How can i use a Gradient Color for a backgroundColor or other normal Color properties in Flutter..?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, gradient

suppose i want to use this **gradient** color

```
final myGradient = LinearGradient(
    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
    end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    colors: [
      const Color(0xFFF8A150).withOpacity(0.09),
      const Color(0xFFF15B2C).withOpacity(0.98)
    ]);
```

actually i want to do this like

`backgroundColor = myGradient`

instead of
 `backgroundColor: Colors.red`

can i use this use this with out **Container**

Comment: In which widget you want to apply this color? I did not properly get that why you want "without container"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this with container...

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: myGradient
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the gradient of the app from the top of the appbar to the end of the screen, just wrap your scaffold with a decorated container and add `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0)` to your scaffold and all scaffolds children like the appbar or bottomNavbar. You need a container to add gradient colors to your scaffold. Scaffold's backgroundColor parameter does not accept any LinerGradient.

```
return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.red],
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter),
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0),
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent.withOpacity(0),
            title: const Text("Test"),
          ),
          body: Home(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code I think Without Container you don't apply Gradient Color Refer [**`LinearGradient`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html)

Your color declaration:

```
final myGradient = LinearGradient(
    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
    end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    colors: [
      const Color(0xFFF8A150).withOpacity(0.09),
      const Color(0xFFF15B2C).withOpacity(0.98)
    ]);
```

Your Widget:

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: myGradient,
        ),
        child: const Center(
          child: Text(
            'Gradient Color Background',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 40,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]